# SVG radialGradient spreadMethod not rendering properly

Tags: html, svg

I'm just learning the SVG format and am trying to create a radial gradient with a `reflect` spreadMethod, but my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) all seem to be rendering it incorrectly. As you can see in the screenshot below from the [MDN gradients tutorial page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients), only the default value, `Pad`, seems to work. The left, titled "Screenshot" is how they're stating it should look and the right, titled "Live sample" is how my browser actually renders it. `repeat` and `reflect` have hard, non-gradient edges.

[image: Expected gradient vs. actual]

It also behaves this way in my own attempts. Here is the code from the "Live Sample":

```
<svg width="220" height="220" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="GradientPad" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4" fx="0.75" fy="0.75" spreadMethod="pad">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="GradientRepeat" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4" fx="0.75" fy="0.75" spreadMethod="repeat">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="GradientReflect" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.4" fx="0.75" fy="0.75" spreadMethod="reflect">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#GradientPad)"></rect>
    <rect x="10" y="120" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)"></rect>
    <rect x="120" y="120" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#GradientReflect)"></rect>

    <text x="15" y="30" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12pt">Pad</text>
    <text x="15" y="140" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12pt">Repeat</text>
    <text x="125" y="140" fill="white" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12pt">Reflect</text>

</svg>
```

What can cause this?

Comment: Perhaps your graphics driver is buggy. My Firefox (49) on my Mac has the live pretty close to the screenshots display in all cases.

Comment: Works for me in FF also. But broken in Chrome 53. [Looks like it is a known problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=644032)

Comment: This is a known Chrome/Windows bug that the assigned Chrome engineer is having trouble replicating - for some reason.